# The mounting a folder to a Docker image remains indefinitely stuck

Tags: docker, mount, docker-image

I'm trying to mount a folder to a docker image in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
(base) raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker image ls
REPOSITORY                         TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
docker.tigergraph.com/tigergraph   latest    6c55bb15e2a6   7 days ago    10.6GB
hello-world                        latest    feb5d9fea6a5   6 weeks ago   13.3kB


(base) raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker run -t -i -v /home/raphy/ConceptNet/ 6c55bb15e2a6
```

It doesn't give any error, but it remains indefinitely stuck

Update 1)

```
(base) raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker run -t -i -v /home/raphy
/ConceptNet:/6c55bb15e2a6/ConceptNet bash
Unable to find image 'bash:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/bash
a0d0a0d46f8b: Pull complete 
ae2d64a5f3ef: Pull complete 
1e5367194cc8: Pull complete 
Digest:
```

sha256:91767623eb341f1717bb37b059e77e8de439c8044064808f6f9bfdc942e8d30c
Status: Downloaded newer image for bash:latest
bash-5.1# ^C

What am I doing wrongly?

SOLVED in this way:

```
(base) raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker run -d -p 14022:22 -p 9000:9000 -p
14240:14240 --name tigergraph --ulimit nofile=1000000:1000000 -v 
~/ConceptNet/:/home/tigergraph/myconceptnet -t 
docker.tigergraph.com/tigergraph:latest
```

https://docs.tigergraph.com/start/get-started/docker#2.-prepare-a-shared-folder-on-host-os-to-be-shared-with-docker-container

Comment: `-v` options probably expects: <localdir>:<docker dir> format. So should be `-v /home/raphy/ConceptNet:/some/docker/dir`

Comment: @kiner_shah Thank you for helping. (base) raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker run -t -i -v /home/raphy/ConceptNet:/6c55bb15e2a6/ConceptNet
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.

Comment: Yes, run will require some command to be run. Not sure which image is that, but you can specify some command like `bash` after `run` and see what it outputs.

Comment: Please don't post in the comments, edit and update the post, it's difficult to read in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker command is insufficient to run tigergraph... it's not a simple run command will do, follow the instruction at https://docs.tigergraph.com/start/get-started/docker

Comment: Thank you @gohm'c . I've already followed the indications there

Comment: Are you sure? You are using anonymous bind but the instruction has said you need to provide at least one bind volume. Also your run command is totally different from the instruction.

Comment: I removed image and container  and start from scratch again

Comment: Is a **very** big image... there are steps to follow after the container is up, every run parameters is important, don't skip any of them.  Also, watch your machine memory usage. Consider mark it as answer to help next person who try to run tigergraph.

Answer (score 1):

your intention is to bind a local path on your host to your container, but what you are really doing now is attaching a new local empty volume to `/home/raphy/ConceptNet/` on your container, just exec:

`docker exec {your container id} ls /home/raphy/ConceptNet/`

to see the path is created inside your container.

also you can use:

`docker inspect {your container id} | less`

and check the "Mounts" part to see what volumes you have really attached to your container, the output will be something like:

```
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "43f6d9846728547b77666705d2b5a4be1d1e644af80f3bb53d86fe105f57bfc6",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/43f6d9846728547b77666705d2b5a4be1d1e644af80f3bb53d86fe105f57bfc6/_data",
                "Destination": "/home/raphy/ConceptNet/",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
```

while

`"Name": "43f6d9846728547b77666705d2b5a4be1d1e644af80f3bb53d86fe105f57bfc6"`

is the name of the volume you've unintentionally created and attached on path   `/home/raphy/ConceptNet/` in your container.

if you want to mount a local directory to your container, just use:

```
sudo docker run -t -i -v /home/raphy/ConceptNet/:/some_path/ 6c55bb15e2a6
```

and if you want to have shell inside your container its better to include your command at the end of docker run like:

```
sudo docker run -t -i -v /home/raphy/ConceptNet/:/some_path/ 6c55bb15e2a6 /bin/sh
```

Comment: Thank you @Aref Riant for your kind explanation. Although I solved using the indications found in the TigerGraph's documentation, your kind explanation are very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-v, --volume=[host-src:]container-dest[:<options>]:
```

[Reference Link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems)